# how can I know how a popup menu was closed?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, calendar, datepicker

I have a WPF DatePicker, and like any datepicker, it has a built-in calendar that you can open by clicking on the small calendar icon.

this calendar is put in a popup menu, so that it behaves like one, i.e.: once it is opened, there are 2 ways to close it:

- Validate you choice (click on a date with the mouse, hit "Enter" with a date highlighted, etc...)
- cancel (hit "Echap", click outside the popup, etc...)

My problem is, I need to know which one was used, and I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Right now I listen to the "CalendarClosedEvent" but it doesn't tell me *How* the calendar was closed.

I also used the "PreviewKeyDownEvent" to trap the "Echap" key, which works well, except it does not cover the case when the user clicks outside the calendar to close it.

Is there a way to do this? if so, what is it?

(NB: I'd be happy with a generic answer about the popup menu object and not the calendar object in the datePicker)

Answer (score 1):

For the DatePicker at least, you can set the SelectedDate to null (which is actually the default so, just leave it). Then the SelectedDateChanged fires any time the user clicks inside the control.

This is the only thing I could find to mark a difference. Hope it helps.

Comment: actually, the reason why I want to know *how* the calendar was closed, is because I want to reset the displaydate to the previous value (in my own format) if it is "canceled", so your solution won't work in my case.

Comment: Hmm, it should. The DisplayDate and the SelectedDate are different properties. When the SelectedDate changes set a "clickedFalg". Then, in the CalendarClosed event check the flag. If the user clicked on the control then let processing happen. If they clicked off the control - set the SelectedDate back to null and the DisplayDate to the previous value. 

I'm not seeing a problem.

Comment: no, it does not work, here is why: let's say I start with an empty box: DisplayDate = "". then I open the calendar. Default SelectedDate is set to DateTime.Today (or null, but it does not impair the following:). then, I use the arrow Keys to highlight an other Date. SelectedDate is changed to this new date (so your flag would be "true"), and then I hit "echap". With your solution, my DisplayDate would be the last selectedDate, instead of "". This is *exactly* what is causing me trouble actually ^^

Comment: CRAP! You're right. Now you ruined what I was going to use it for :) . Well, back to the drawing board.

Comment: How about we add one more event handler - KeyDown. Check e.Key, if it's Escape then set the clickedFalg back to false. So far in my testing this works like a champ. Still doesn't excuse the lack of a notification flag in the framework.

Comment: Further testing has proven that this still doesn't quite make it. If you use the arrow keys to select a date then use the mouse to click off the control - You still have a SelectedDate and a true flag. I'll keep plugging at it, but I may have to cut off keyboard input to the calendar.